# infopath form based on data from other infopath forms

Tags: infopath, form

i have library with items (InfoPath form that needs to be filled out). each item / form has fields for buyers...ets. I want to have in each new open form available entries which were added in other form. Example. I open new form, wite in Company field company name, lets say name is X. Than i save form. When i open new, blank, form I would like to have that X company availabe in my compayn field to choose, not to write it again

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have a dropdown where you want to show company name

Then, in your InfoPath form in which you want to show company name,

1. Right click on drop down and choose properties.
2. From data source, select list or library.
3. Add receive data connection to the infopath form url and choose the field you want to show.

Comment: Hi, thanks for quick answer. Will this insert other thata from that company too, or must i insert them manually? thanks

Comment: You can create aa data connection in your infopath form to query another list. That way you get multiple values based on single value. Now using rules you can control which value goes where in your form where you want to show.

Comment: you mean something like this: http://www.wonderlaura.com/Lists/Posts/Post.aspx?ID=129